# About parentheses in a string

Tags: java, c++, string, algorithm

In an interview I was asked to solve the following problem.

Given a string, count the number of parenthesis pairs in it. For example, if the string is `s = "()()"`, there are 3 pairs:

```
s[0], s[1]
s[0], s[3]
s[2], s[3]
```

I wrote the following code:

```
int count(char* s) {
  int left = 0;
  int pair = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    char c = s[i];
    if (c == '(') {
      left++;
    } else if (c == ')') {
      pair += left;
    }
  }
  return pair;
}
```

Then came another problem:

Given a length L, and a count N, determine the string `s` with `strlen(s) == L` and `count(s) == N` (`count` is the function I wrote above; `s` should only contain parentheses). For example, if L is 4 and N is 3, the string is "()()".

I found that, in the example, `s` can also be "((()" or "()))". It would be better to print all the strings that meet the requirement.

Anyone can solve the second problem? Thank you. It would be really nice if you write java or c/c++ code for solution.

Comment: Do you know sliding window technique?

Comment: Yeah. Can it be used here? Could you please explain?

Comment: Great, wait few seconds.

Comment: Are you trying to find a string of the right length with the right count?  Or the number of strings of that length with the right count?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I misunderstood the question  :(

Comment: For example, if L is 4 and N is 3, is it sufficient to output "((()" or do you need to know how many strings work?

Comment: The interviewer just let me generate a string of the right length with the right count. I pointed out there are many possible answers. I think it's better to generate all of them.

Comment: There's a one-to-one correspondence between strings of length N and binary numbers with N bits. A solution follows immediately from this.

Comment: @David Schwartz, during the interview I considered this correspondence, e.g., ()() -> 1010, ((()->1110, ()))->1000. However I was not able to build a certain relationship between the binary numbers and the pair count (3 in this example). Can you provide a solution based on this idea? Thank you.

Comment: @shengbinmeng You don't need such a correspondence. You already have code to measure the pair count.

Comment: @David Schwartz, are you indicating a brute-force solution that checks all the strings of that length one by one and see if the count is right? I think this can solve, but the complexity is 2^n...

Comment: @shengbinmeng I would start there, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a dynamic programming solution written in Java. The main idea is to recursively build all possible strings that satisfy given conditions. Strings are built from the end to the beginning, by adding either `)` or `(`. Let us denote with

```
public static List<String> rec(int len, int n, int r)
```

a method that takes three parameters: `len` is a length of a part of string that is still left to be constructed, `n` is value of `count` function, and `r` is a number of right parentheses used so far in the process of building string. For example, if we are looking for all strings of the form "_ _ _ ( ) )", then `len = 3`, and `r = 2`.  It is easy to check that:

```
rec(len, n, r) = { rec(len - 1, n, r + 1), rec(len - 1, n - r, r) }
```

Note that we basically consider two cases - strings that we get when we add a right parenthesis (in that case `r` is incremented), and strings that we get when we add a left parenthesis to the current string (in that case `n` becomes `n - r` because this new left parenthesis matches all right parentheses that were put so far).

Final solution that we are looking for is obviously `rec(len, n, 0)`.

Code:

```
    private static HashMap<String, List<String>> cache = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public static List<String> solution(int len, int n) {
        return rec(len, n, 0);
    }

    public static List<String> rec(int len, int n, int r) {
        String key = len + "#" + n + "#" + r;
        if (cache.containsKey(key))
            return cache.get(key);
        List<String> retVal = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (len == 1) {
            if (n == r)
                retVal.add("(");
            if (n == 0)
                retVal.add(")");
            return retVal;
        }
        List<String> rightParenSet = rec(len - 1, n, r + 1);
        List<String> leftParenSet = rec(len - 1, n - r, r);

        for (String s : rightParenSet)
            retVal.add(s + ")");
        for (String s : leftParenSet)
            retVal.add(s + "(");

        cache.put(key, retVal);

        return retVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = solution(4, 3);
        for(String s : strings)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Two observations:

- cache is used in order to prevent calculating same strings over and
  over and to reduce time complexity
- this is a top-down solution; bottom-up approach would be even
  more efficient

Comment: solution(1, 0) return "(" only, ")" is missing

Answer (score 4):

Generating a string of the right length with the right count is an exercise in math.

First let `k` be the floor of the square root of `N`.  The shortest string that will generate `k2` strings is of length `2k`.  It looks like `(...()...)`.

The shortest string that will generate `k2+k` strings is of length `2k+1`.  You just append one `)` to the previous string.  For `N` between `k2` and `k2+k` you just slide the left-most `)` over the right number of `(` parentheses.

The shortest string that will generate `k2+2k` strings is of length `2k+2`.  You just append another `)` to the previous string.  For `N` between `k2+k` and `k2+2k` you just slide the left-most `)` over the right number of `(` parentheses.

If `N` is greater than `k2+2k` then you didn't calculate the floor of the square root. :-)

If `L` is shorter than this length, then there is no solution.  If `L` is greater than this length, then you just write this solution and append the right number of `(` to the end.

---

The right way to find the number of solutions is to use dynamic programming.  You build up a table of for all things of length `i`, how many solutions have `j` open parentheses with `m` total pairs.  (There are standard ways to turn this dynamic programming solution into a way of listing the solutions if you want.  But the list will generally be very long.)

Comment: I got your math idea. Could you please check if you have some typos in the 4th paragraph? "k^2+k strings is of length 2k+1" should be "k^2+2k strings is of length 2k+2" there?

Comment: @shengbinmeng Yeah, uncorrected cut and paste.  Sorry.